# How to use mongoose update, and update a embed document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i've already read mongoose document, and i still can't figure out how to update document.

i use node, express, and mongodb with mongoose.

this is a collection in my mongodb...

```
{ "title" : "this is a title",
    "_id" : ObjectId( "4f7a92554ad893f322000004" ),
  "nodes" : [ 
               { "title" : "this is node 1",
                   "_id" : ObjectId( "4f7a92554ad893f322000009" ) }, 
               { "title" : "this is node 2",
                   "_id" : ObjectId( "4f7a92554ad893f322000008" ) }, 
               { "title" : "this is node 3",
                   "_id" : ObjectId( "4f7a92554ad893f322000007" ) }, 
               { "title" : "this is node 4",
                   "_id" : ObjectId( "4f7a92554ad893f322000006" ) }, 
               { "title" : "this is node 5",
                   "_id" : ObjectId( "4f7a92554ad893f322000005" ) }
            ]
}
```

how do i update nodes embed document ???

```
app.put('/api/paper/:pid/:nid', function(req, res) {
    var PaperModel = mongoose.model('papers', Paper);
    PaperModel.update({_id: req.params.pid, 'nodes._id': req.params.nid}, {title: 'this         is a new node title'}, function(error, result) {
        console.dir(result);
    });
});
```

it's not working.

how do i update embed array "nodes"

nodes._id: 4f7a92554ad893f322000009 title: this is node 1 to title :  this is a new title ?

Answer (score 7):

```
PaperModel.update(
    {_id: req.params.pid, 'nodes._id': req.params.nid}
  , { $set: {'nodes.$.title': 'this is a new node title'}}
  , function(error, result) {
      console.dir(result);
    }
);
```

Note that this can only update one sub-document at a time (mongodb limitation).